# How to run docker-based mssql-tools using a regular way

Tags: docker, mssql-tools

I have installed a mssql server using docker microsoft/mssql-server-linux. It behaves the same as a regular mssql server. i.e my client can access it exactly the same way they access a regular mssql server.

Now I am installing mssql-tools using docker:
mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools

Looks like in order to use the mssql-tools to access a mssql server (they want sqlcmd/bcp), my client has to run

```
docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools
```

and then run

```
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -U sa”
```

under a new interface

```
root@1396d2e50672:
```

It is not convenient because he has to change all the code where sqlcmd/bcp has been directly called to access the mssql server.

Is it how a container based mssql-tools works? How can I install a mssql-tool container without having the clients change their API?

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to run it?

There are multiple strategies [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-docker?view=sql-server-ver15) This refers to the server but that contains the tools as well

What I usually do is pass in an [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime) change the [workdir](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#workdir) to a volume mount and mount a volume of scripts.

```
docker run \
    --entrypoint /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd \
    -w /mymount  -v ./myscripts:/mymount \
  mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools \
    -S 127.0.0.1 -U sa -i myscriptinmymount.sql
```

Note the options to sqlcmd are passed as usual after the image

untested...

Comment: Thanks KeepCalmAndCarryOn: I am reading you answer. to answer your question: How do you want to run it? I want to run the mssql-tools and after that, my client will still run sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -U sa the same way as before. They do not need to know if the new Sqlcmd is from the regular mssql-tools or from the docker-based mssql. how I install it is transparent to them.